# Ubuntu is turning on automatically after I shut it down!

Tags: 16.04, shutdown

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. After 5 seconds of shutting my PC down it turns on automatically. I can suspend it only. Can you help me to fix this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately no, because it's hardware and unrelated to Ubuntu.

Comment: @MichaelBay What do you mean by "hardware problem"? The PC was running Windows10 and did have this kind of problems. Can you explain more, please?

Comment: Sounds like you enabled some sort of LAN wake up, this can not be Ubuntu.

Comment: Indeed, some sort of wake-up feature, either LAN, keyboard/mouse or other, is quite plausible. Please check your BIOS/UEFI settings. Also in this cases posting the hardware specs is useful. There's always the odd model with very specific quirks that someone may have reported already. You can [edit] your question anytime.

Comment: I've experienced this on 17.04 & 17.10. In my case, it is because I have a wireless mouse USB receiver connected to a port. Frustratingly, I have shut off all wake-on-keyboard/mouse events in my BIOS. As an experiment, unplug all USB devices and Ethernet before you shut down.
 (Obviously, your mouse should be disconnected just after you click the shut down button). This way, you can eliminate all external factors that may be "waking up" your computer. If your computer doesn't wake up, you can begin a process of elimination by selectively keeping only one device plugged in each time you test.

Comment: Is there any specific software to control this? If no, how can I change it from BIOS or UEFI setting? Thanks!

Comment: I have checked my BIOS settings. Both Network & WLAN wake-up are disabled.

Comment: Same problem here